# Deploying on hardhat using gnosis-safe as deployer

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, hardhat, gnosis-safe

Is there any approach to deploy smart contracts in hardhat using my gnosis safe as deployer?
I had a look over hardhat plugins but I haven't found anything.
Any idea?